# How do I run rdesktop in a new x session?

Tags: xrdp, rdesktop

I use Ctrl-Alt-F1 through Ctrl-Alt-F6 for CLI and Ctrl-Alt-F7 for the Xsession.  I would like to run rdesktop in fullscreen Ctrl-Alt-F8 so that I can switch between them.

Is there a way to either run another xdm/xsession on Ctrl-Alt-F8 and form within it run rdesktop or otherwise have rdesktop display directly to Ctrl-Alt-F8?

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I added these lines to /etc/lightdm.conf:

```
[Seat:1]
xserver-command=/usr/bin/X :1 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:1 -nolisten tcp tty7

[Seat:2]
xserver-command=/usr/bin/X :2 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:2 -nolisten tcp tty8
```

It allows me to switch between the screens with Ctrl-Alt-F7 and Ctrl-Alt-F8.  Each screen requires a login.